# Probability of sum of faces of dice equal to either $7$ or $11$

Tags: probability

> Two dice of different colors are thrown simultaneously. The probability that the sum of the faces appeared is either $7$ or $11$ is
>
> 1. $\dfrac7{36}$
> 2. $\dfrac49$
> 3. $\dfrac23$
> 4. $\dfrac59$

The answer is $\dfrac49$ but why?

What I did was:

Total Outcomes = $36$

Sum is $7 = (1,6), (6,1), (2,5), (5,2), (3,4), (4,3)$

Sum is $11 = (5,6), (6,5)$

Probability  $= \dfrac8{36} = \dfrac29$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The options are: $\frac{7}{36};\frac{1}{9};\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{9}$, correct answer: $\frac{4}{9}$?

Comment: $2/9$ is correct.  Why do you think the answer is $4/9$?

Comment: Edited ( not 1/9 but 4/9)

Comment: this was a question of an entrance exam and the answer key says answer is 4/9.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer, unless the problem you posted is quite unclear (are the dice really six-sided?).

Even if we entirely ignore the colors of the two dice, mark one die as "I" and the other die as "II".

As you say, the only possible pairs are $(1;6);(6;1);(2;5);(5;2);(3;4);(4;3);(5;6);(6;5)$, these are $8$ out of $36$ possible pairs.

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural.  You should have written two dice and one die.

Answer (score 1):

You are very much correct, also, 4/9 is not even an answer in the choices given.
[image: a nice lil diagram to visualise the probabilities]

Probability of the sum being 7 = 6/36 = 1/6 = 3/18
Probability of the sum being 11 = 2/36 = 1/18
Probability of the sum being 7 or 11 = 1/18 + 3/18 = 4/18 = 2/9

Comment: Thanks, but this was a question of an entrance exam. (I have edited my question) and the answer key says answer is 4/9.

Comment: @Shammy they are wrong